# Quarterly Timer job

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I am creating a timer job that sends mail on 1 day of every quarter of a year. I have written the code. Only I have  to add code to schedule it. Please help me.

Comment: If that is custom timer job.. You can define the schedule and update the job with schedule ..

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a timer job. Use a Windows Scheduled Task instead. Not only will this increase farm stability as you don't have custom code, you can also deploy code with zero downtime, and your schedule can be far more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Is it timer job which will run inside the SharePoint or a Scheduled Task?

- For SharePoint Timer Job, you have to deploy it in your SharePoint Farm.check this blog post for more info: http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-procedures-to-create-a-Timer-Job-in-SharePoint-2013
- If you want to run it as Schedule Job( which is recommended approach), then you can create the schedule task with all required parameters, go to Task Scheduler from Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools. [image]